# style.color if-statement not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make some javascript for entering/exiting (onfocus/onblur) textfields. I want to have faded "pretyped" text which disappears when you enter the field. The problem is testing  to see if the value of the textbox should be removed or not. One way to is to check the value of the textfield upon entering, and if it's equal to the pretyped text, then the value is set to nothing, like so:

```
if(field.value=='username'){
    field.value='';  //removes pretyped text
    field.style.color='rgb(0, 0, 0,)';  //turns text black
}
```

However, the user can replicate the pretyped text, and upon entering that text, it will also be removed. I guess this is a minor problem, but I want to be as professional as possible. To fix this problem, I tried testing for the color of the text in the textfield, because the user is not able to replicate the color of the grayed pretyped text. I used this code:

```
if(field.style.color=='rgb(150, 150, 150)'){ //default color in CSS
    field.value='';  //removes pretyped text
    field.style.color='rgb(0, 0, 0,)';  //turns text black
}
```

This doesn't work for some reason. The pretyped text remains, and the color doesn't change. I'm pretty sure that the syntax for accessing the CSS color is correct (field.style.color), as it works to set the color to black (but only when testing for the value of the field).

Any help is appreciated :)

EDIT: there is no extra comma in my actual code.

Comment: While the syntax is probably ok, how the browser wants to represent the color internally probably differs from your string. Check it with `console.log(field.style.color)` to see what string the browser is using, and therefore what string you need to compare in your `if ()`.

Comment: Are you referring to placeholder text? It's a standard HTML field behavior...

Comment: If you want to be professional about it use the placeholder attribute instead of default text in inputs

Comment: Why can't you simply raise a flag to determine if the field contain boilerplate text or not? The user have entered something -> remove the flag. The user blurred the field and there's empty string there -> raise flag again. If flag is raised, display the boilerplate, if it's not -- remove it.

Comment: I'll also point out that if the CSS rule is inherited, then `field.style.color` is likely to be `undefined` since it wasn't explicitly set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @MichaelBerkowski said, the value of `field.style.color` is undefined.

**Option 1**

If you set that value in javascript:

```
txt.style.color = 'rgb(150, 150, 150)';
```

Your code should work. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nevster/Havza/).

**Option 2**

You could also use:

```
window.getComputedStyle(this).getPropertyValue('color');
```

This will get the value set in CSS. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nevster/Havza/4/).

Comment: @August I tried that in jsfiddle and it appears not. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nevster/Havza/1/).

Comment: Thank you, this works. Do you think this is the best method though?